# Why isn't my WPF datagrid being populated?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagridview

I'm following the tutorial here: http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/datagrid-control/introduction/

I set up the DataGrid, created a collection with the data source, and set the DataGrid's ItemsSource to that collection. Upon running the program, it seems the number of rows is correct, but all the rows are blank. What do I need to change to get the data to show correctly?

xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="Task_Timer.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Task Timer" Height="284" Width="598" MinWidth="500" MinHeight="400">
    <Grid Margin="10">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <DataGrid x:Name="ProcessBox" Margin="0" SelectionMode="Extended" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" GridLinesVisibility="None" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsManipulationEnabled="True" IsReadOnly="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="285">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Process" Binding="{Binding ProcessName}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Memory" Binding="{Binding Memory}" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
        <Button Content="Button" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

C#:

```
namespace Task_Timer
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            List<ProcessContainer> items = new List<ProcessContainer>();
            foreach (Process process in Process.GetProcesses())
            {
                items.Add(new ProcessContainer(process.ProcessName, 10));
            }

            ProcessBox.ItemsSource = items;
        }
    }

    public class ProcessContainer
    {
        public string ProcessName;
        public int Memory;

        public ProcessContainer(string name, int memory)
        {
            ProcessName = name;
            Memory = memory;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing **get** and **set**. You need to **set** the value of your Properties inside the Class **ProcessContainer**

Change it like this,

```
public class ProcessContainer
        {
            public string ProcessName {get;set;}
            public int Memory { get; set; }

            public ProcessContainer(string name, int memory)
            {
                ProcessName = name;
                Memory = memory;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Interesting. I always figured the get and set was implicitly there. Worked anyway, thank you!

Comment: this answer may mislead others from the actual reason. In fact only ***properties*** can be used in binding, ***fields*** can't (not mention other bad things in user's code).

Comment: @KingKing is the "bad things" a reference to my code or the code in this answer?

Comment: @ssb of course it's in your code. Such as you should use an `ObservableCollection` instead of a `List` (a simple List does not support notifying property changed as well as notifying collection changed). Also the properties in your ViewModel should also be notified with changes by implementing the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface for your ViewModel. It's all about programming pattern, especially **MVVM** which should be used in WPF applications. However if your DataGrid is supposed to show data only, it's OK.

Comment: @KingKing well lucky for you I learned that the hard way and went through a rather long ordeal fixing it! At any rate if you see a bad thing in my (or others') code I think it's fine to call it bad, but I hope you can at least mention why. You might have saved me an hour otherwise. I fully admit I am entirely ignorant of how one should properly work with WPF.

Comment: @ssb it's not easy to give a full explanation. What about the time? what if the OP asks more and more ... The importance is to solve the problem ***asked*** in this question. Also I'm not a teacher, I'm also a learner (maybe forever). And I'm sure if you continue learning yourself, all the so-called bad things here will be realized and avoided by yourself. Anyway thank you for your advice. Next time, I won't say anything about the OP's code. Unless I have free time to add more and more explanation (but it may not never happen, so busy now).

Answer (score 0):

change your ProcessContainer class as follows

```
 public class ProcessContainer
    {
        private string process;

        public string ProcessName
        {
            get { return process; }
            set { process = value; }
        }

        private int memory;

        public int Memory
        {
            get { return memory; }
            set { memory = value; }
        }


        public ProcessContainer(string name, int memory)
        {
            ProcessName = name;
            Memory = memory;
        }
    }
```